# How to adjust bracket size in a latex axis label

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I would like to create a label for a matplotlib plot like

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(range(5))
plt.ylabel(r"$A \ [m^{3}]$")
```

but the square brackets do not have the right size to accommodate the superscript:

[image]

How can I adapt their size (maybe something like \left and \right in latex)?